# How to get the difference of two values in two piecharts

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Hello I have two `Piechart`s with percentage values declareted.

```
Chart1
.width(250)
.height(250)
.slicesCap(4)
.innerRadius(0)
.dimension(statusTotalDim)

.title(function(d){return "At this part there are " + d.value +" "+ d.key+ " Directories! ";})
.colors(d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#ff2222","#4855ff"]))

.label(function (d) {
    if (Chart1.hasFilter() && !Chart1.hasFilter(d.key)) {
        return d.key + ' (0%)';
    }
    var label = d.key;
    if (all.value()) {
        label += ' (' + Math.floor(d.value / all.value() * 100) + '%)';
    }
    return label ;
})
.group(countPer);
```

Thats one of the charts. the other chart is the same but only with a filter more.

So for example I have in chart 1 this values `45%` and `55%`
In chart 2 I have the values `40%` and `60%`

How is possible to get difference of `chart1(40%)-chart2(45%) = -5%`

Is it possible to take the labels and make a measure separately?

Thank you very very much!

Comment: i think you have confused chart1 with chart2 values in your description at the end.

Comment: ok .
there are different dimensions and countings for each chart. So i just like t know how i can extraxt this values from d.key..
Thanks QHarr

Comment: Do you want the difference in the values or the difference in the percentages?

Comment: yes right! just compare them and see if theres a difference like -5% or +5%